# To get Standard ECG from PhysioNet?

Tags: cardiology, electrocardiography, research-tools, research-process

I am trying to get standard ECG by using PhysioNet's [ATM](http://physionet.org/cgi-bin/atm/ATM) with parameters

[image]

but I get

[image]

It should be something like

[image]

**How can you get complete standard 12-lead ECG out of Physionet database?**

Comment: Programmatically attempt here http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/52955/86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PTB Diagnostic ECG database [here](http://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/ptbdb/). 
Review [here](http://www.beecardia.com/physiobank/database/ptbdb/).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that all leads are available.

I looked at the **Signals** combobox for different databases. This combobox seems to be the list of all available leads.

For example, take a look at **iafdb** (Intracardiac Atrial Fibrillation Database). It will plot you an ECG containing leads II, V1 and aVF and some other leads.

Another example is the EEG database **eegmmidb** (EEG Motor Movement/Image Dataset) which contains many leads.

Look also at the **mimic2wdb/39** (MIMIC II waveform database, version 3 part 9) which contains 4 ECG leads and some other parameters like breath rate.

Comment: I do not understand how this work has managed to use Physionet's data and got such a 12-lead solution: http://web.utk.edu/~xzhao9/research/Physionet2011/ECGQuality.html Do you?

Comment: **Is any of these databases AAMI standarded?** There is no 12 lead AAMI databases available online. I verified the St. Petersburg database and it is not AAMI - big entanglement of energy. They have problems with some analog components and other things - too many unknown variables.

Comment: How can you get programmatically data with `rdsamp`? I extended the thread here http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/52955/86

Answer (score 3):

As another answer suggested, it's a matter of choosing a database that has all of the leads. The St Petersburg INCART 12-lead Arrhythmia Database (incartdb) contains all 12 signals. [Here](http://physionet.org/physiobank/database/incartdb/) is the directory. The tracings are available by selecting it from the drop-down menu on the page you linked.

Comment: Is this AAMI standard data?

Comment: @Masi I don't know. There are several email contacts listed on the page I linked. You may want to write to them to obtain more info about the data.

Comment: I contacted them. I will write here when I get the answer. In ambulatory ECGs, there is the situation that MIT-BIH is the only available AAMI standard data when also requirement that two datasets of one patient (particularly patient #201).

Comment: @Masi does it need to be ambulatory?  Was the UT example from a database?  I didn't think they had one.  Anyway looking at St Petersburg it appears to be AAMI

Comment: @AtlLED It does not need to be ambulatory. What is UT? Do you have reasons why ST Petersburg is AAMI?

Comment: @AtlLED St Petersburg database is not AAMI. I verified this through a long process made by me and my friends. They have problems in many components of their system. So there is no AAMI standarded 12-lead databases online.