# Any databases with AAMI ECG and ECHO?

Tags: cardiology, database, electrocardiography, research-tools, research-process

There is no AAMI 12-lead ECG databases available online. 
All of them have problems. 
I and my friends finally finalised our tests with [St Petersburg](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/21870/86). 
It is not AAMI.

So the next step is to search any ECG databases with some leads (at least lead 2) with ECHO data.

**Is there any AAMI standarded ECG databases with ECHO data?**
This data need to be from the same patient.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is PTB Diagnostic ECG database [here](http://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/ptbdb/). 
However, its AAMI verification is still under process [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/34345/86). 
Some ECHO findings also there.